# I want to display my one column horizontally in Crystal Report detail section

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I want to display my record horizontally just one column in the appropriate area:

[image]

But when I go to section expert => detail => multiply column and specify the width and height, then it shows the column across the complete page like this:

[image]

Comment: Try using SubReport

Answer (score 0):

Insert a Group on 'S. No.'
Show the info in Group Footer.
And use a detail-level formula and a global string variable to collect all the identifiers into a single formula displayed in the group footer.

Comment: i didnot get you

Comment: i just want to show the barcde detail in horizantal format as in first pic